# Extract elements from a XML with Python

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to extract some specifics elements from a XML. I download the data from an API and save in a variable as `sitios2`.

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<lista><sitio sitio_id="131997">
<custom_id/>    <lang></lang>
    <fecha_alta>2017-06-22 22:38:18</fecha_alta>
<observaciones/>    <ultimas24hrs>  <item id='imps24ad'>0</item>
    <item id='clicks24'>0</item>
    <item id='imps24blank'>0</item>
    <item id='ctr24'>0</item>
</ultimas24hrs>
<fecha_baja/>   <sitio_id>131997</sitio_id>
    <estado>1</estado>
    <hex_sitio_id>2039D
</hex_sitio_id>
    <url>https://www.google.com.ar/</url>
    <nombre>google.com.ar</nombre>
</sitio>
```

My code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(sitios2)
for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
for item in root.iter('item'):
    print(item.attrib)
```

output I have is:

```
('sitio', {'sitio_id': '131997'})

{'id': 'imps24ad'}
{'id': 'clicks24'}
```

what i'm looking for is a txt file with all data but only with the information I need:

```
sitio_id="131997" 
fecha_alta 2017-06-22 22:38:18
imps24blank 0
estado 1 
url https://www.google.com.ar/
nombre google.com.ar
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for. Output a (stripped down) xml file again, the one you posted in the end of your post? Or extracting certain elements into a python-type, like a dict? What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: Your XML tags don't match.

Comment: I just edited @ascripter

Comment: Yes, it's indeed a broken XML file. If that's what you need to handle, a regex-approach might be best. Otherwise fix your XML first.

Comment: I fix the XML, do you have an idea how I can extract what I'm looking for? @ascripter

Comment: If you fix the XML, I suppose the tree parser will give you valid structure that you can play with (iterate over, catch the elements you need, create text file from the result)

Comment: Okey but this XML I extracted from the API and I don´t know why you say I need to fix because I don`t know anything about the xml files and structure :/ @ascripter

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support)

```
for child in root.find("./sitio"):
    print(child.tag, child.text)
for item in root.findall('./sitio/ultimas24hrs/item'):
    print(item.tag, item.attrib, item.text)
```

output:

```
custom_id None
lang None
fecha_alta 2017-06-22 22:38:18
observaciones None
ultimas24hrs   
fecha_baja None
sitio_id 131997
estado 1
hex_sitio_id 2039D

url https://www.google.com.ar/
nombre google.com.ar
item {'id': 'imps24ad'} 0
item {'id': 'clicks24'} 0
item {'id': 'imps24blank'} 0
item {'id': 'ctr24'} 0
```

**NOTE:**
Your provided xml is not valid, so I assumed that your xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<lista>
  <sitio sitio_id="131997">
    <custom_id/>
    <lang/>
    <fecha_alta>2017-06-22 22:38:18</fecha_alta>
    <observaciones/>
    <ultimas24hrs>
      <item id="imps24ad">0</item>
      <item id="clicks24">0</item>
      <item id="imps24blank">0</item>
      <item id="ctr24">0</item>
    </ultimas24hrs>
    <fecha_baja/>
    <sitio_id>131997</sitio_id>
    <estado>1</estado>
    <hex_sitio_id>2039D</hex_sitio_id>
    <url>https://www.google.com.ar/</url>
    <nombre>google.com.ar</nombre>
  </sitio>
</lista>
```

Comment: The second for, I need the inner values: `item {'id': 'imps24blank'} "0"`

Comment: and also, why I can extract the information for only 1 sitio?? because I have more information as before but different sitio_id in the xml

Comment: @MartinBouhier if you need just item `id="imps24blank"` you can add if into for statement

Comment: how can I mix all values as `custom_id None
lang None
fecha_alta 2017-06-22 22:38:18
observaciones None
ultimas24hrs   
fecha_baja None
sitio_id 131997
estado 1
hex_sitio_id 2039D
url https://www.google.com.ar/
nombre google.com.ar
item {'id': 'imps24ad'} 0
item {'id': 'clicks24'} 0
item {'id': 'imps24blank'} 0
item {'id': 'ctr24'} 0`

Comment: What do you mean by "mix"?

Comment: as you can see in the comment.. the first for and the second all together

Comment: @MartinBouhier title of your question is "Extract elements from a XML with Python" and I think the answer provides you enough knowledgement to do it. I just say you that you can concatenate two list, choice data what you want and finally write a file.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through `sitio` elements, and use XPath to find all information needed within current `sitio` in every iteration :

```
for s in root.findall('sitio'):
    id = s.find('sitio_id')
    fa = s.find('fecha_alta')
    i24 = s.find('*/item[@id="imps24blank"]')
    estado = s.find('estado')
    url = s.find('url')
    nombre = s.find('nombre')

    print(id.tag, id.text)
    print(fa.tag, fa.text)
    print(i24.tag, i24.text)
    print(estado.tag, estado.text)
    print(url.tag, url.text)
    print(nombre.tag, nombre.text)
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/943012)</kbd>**

Break down of the XPath expression used to find `i24` value :

- `*`: find child element of any name
- `/item`: then from such elements, find child elements named `item` where...
- `[@id="imps24blank"]`: ...`id` attribute value equals string "imps24blank"

Comment: I don´t understand how I should create a variable to extract the `imps24blank ` with the results... `i24 = s.find('*/item[@id="imps24blank"]')`don't show me anything

Comment: @MartinBouhier the eval.in demo provided in this answer showcases otherwise, it prints `item 0`. Please create minimal eval.in demo that demonstrate your problem, otherwise I have no idea how to help because the same code works in my demo..

Comment: yes I saw then and I had the results I was looking for! Thanks man! Could you help me with my new questions?? it is very similar with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512286/fix-xml-syntax-errors-in-python?noredirect=1#comment84019908_48512286